# jquery ajax post requests(JSON Object)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to secure ajax post requests because in my website I am sending content through ajax request. And while testing I used some tool to see and manipulate the traffic (data send through ajax post request) even in post request. I am using spring mvc in server side and sending data through j query ajax requests.

**client side code:**

```
var account={
name:'clear',
id :'verbose'
}
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
               dataType: "json",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               data:JSON.stringify(account),
               url:"addUser1.htm",
success : function(response) {

},error:function(e){
}
});
```

And i am getting this object in server side as `@Requestbody method=POST`. Can you please give me some ideas to secure my request and make it invisible to hackers. I am using spring security to prevent unauthorized access server side.

Comment: I don't think there are any other option beside SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Client side scripts and requests can always be manipulated. You need to verify each request on the server side. You can add data to the $_SESSION and validate it. Also check for valid user, user privileges etc. if your projects supports them and CSRF and HTTP referrer should match your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're sending it via POST and use SSL rather than plain old http format.

Hence if you're using HTTPS (SSL) (and please do for anything that needs to be secure) then yes an AJAX request is no more or less safe than a full postback to the server.